# Unity Firebase iOS missing symbol arm64

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know a solution to below error https://pastebin.com/1nd0hkcF.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have successfully ran Unity iOS version on simulator, but running it on a real device throws out an error about some missing symbols from 64arm architecture.

I have tried everything from relinking stuff, downgrading, changing bitcode, architectures. It just keeps throwing the same missing symbol arm64 and linker error after.

Comment: Looking at your linker errors, it looks like the plugin having an issue might actually be this one: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity

Can you confirm?

I'm making this guess from all the `_GoogleSignIn_` and `_GoogleSignInImpl_` function names but the lack of any `firebase` specific ones.

Comment: Further details: if it's working in the simulator but not on a 64 bit build, it's likely using a native library that lacks arm64 symbols. Either that or a `.so` (or `.a` since iOS likes to static link things, this would be inside a `.framework` folder) is missing. You may want to try building https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity from source, and I can formulate a more detailed answer if that's the issue.

Comment: Yeah it was missing arm64 on iOS somehow even though it says iOS is supported on GitHub. I ended up just removing GoogleSignIn from iOS and just having GameCenter there.